# Data is not displaying on UITableViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swifty-json

I can print the symbols in the function getJSON(), but when it comes time to displaying the StockArray, Nothing appears, and when I print StockArray, Nothing appears as well.  I do not know the problem.  Here is the code.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import ObjectMapper
import SwiftyJSON

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    var NumberofRows = 0
        let stockURL = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL+TSLA%22)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&format=json"
    var StockArray = [String]()




    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

//    @IBOutlet weak var StockSymbolLbl: UILabel!
//    @IBOutlet weak var BidSymbolLbl: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getJSON()
//        StockSymbolLbl.text = ""
//        BidSymbolLbl.text = ""


        }

    func getJSON(){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        let url = NSURL(string: self.stockURL)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
                let Symbol: String? = swiftyJSON["query"]["results"]["quote"][0]["symbol"].stringValue
                let bid: String? = swiftyJSON["query"]["results"]["quote"][0]["Change"].stringValue
                print(Symbol!)
                print(bid!)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
//                self.StockSymbolLbl.text? = "\(Symbol!)"
//                self.BidSymbolLbl.text? = "\(bid!)"
                    self.NumberofRows = swiftyJSON["query"]["results"]["quote"].count

                    for i in 0...self.NumberofRows {
                        var stockcount = 0
                        stockcount += i
                        let Stock = swiftyJSON["query"]["results"]["quote"][stockcount]["symbol"].stringValue
                        self.StockArray.append(Stock)
                        print(Stock)
                    }

                }



            }else{
                print("There was an error")
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return NumberofRows
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        if StockArray.count != 0{
            cell.textLabel?.text = StockArray[indexPath.item]
        }

        print(self.StockArray)

        return cell
    }



}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Side-note: The check `StockArray.count != 0` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is redundant because the method is normally never called if the array is empty. Instead return `StockArray.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection` rather than the quasi hard-coded `NumberofRows`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling reload data in getJSON() after the loop?

```
                for i in 0...self.NumberofRows {
                    var stockcount = 0
                    stockcount += i
                    let Stock = swiftyJSON["query"]["results"]["quote"][stockcount]["symbol"].stringValue
                    self.StockArray.append(Stock)
                    print(Stock)
                }
              tableView.reloadData() 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the UITableView in main thread, just after all the data present in the stock array. I'm not the swift guy, but in objective-c corresponding code is following.

```
[[NSOperationqueue mainqueue]
    ^{
        [tableview reloadData];
    }];
```

[NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSOperationQueue/mainQueue)

[UITableView reloaddata](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData)

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** In your `getJSON` method, after appending all your data to the `StockArray` you must call `tableView.reloadData()`.

**More Detailed:**
You are making an async (background -- non blocking) call to fetch your JSON. The controller will create itself before that call has completed, therefore when your controller first opens there is no data to display. Once that async load is complete you can tell your controller that new data exists and that it should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is setting a property observer on the tableView variable:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
      didSet {
           tableView.reloadData()
      }
}
```

Everytime your tableView's contents is changed the reloadData func is called.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of the answers, while adding `tableView.relaodData()` was part of the issue,

I also had to insert

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```

into viewDidLoad()

Thank you once again!